# Syntax Error in map from string to function

Tags: c++, function, dictionary, visual-studio-2012, lambda

I'm getting the following syntax error in Visual Studio 2012:

> 1>...\documents\visual studio 2012\projects...\line.h(21): error C2143: syntax error : missing '`)`' before '`const`'

when attempting to create the following (it is defined in another file) also `tokenList` is a `typedef` for `std::vector<std::string>`:

`extern std::map<std::string,std::function<std::string (const tokenList& tokens)>> evaluateOperator; //<-- This is the line with the error`

where I was hoping to do the following:

```
evaluateOperator["="] = [](const tokenList& tokens) -> std::string
{
    std::string temp("");
            ...
};
```

What am I doing wrong? (I am VERY new to C++11). I would also appreciate any suggestions on how to go about the problem as a whole, that is apply a function on a list of strings based on an input string. Thank you.

EDIT: And this is why SSCEs are so important - I have located the source of the error (after using ICC2013) as being the wrong order of code - the typedef came AFTER the map declaration. Idiotic on my part, but interesting that Intel C++ Compiler 2013 was able to immediately detect the cause of the syntax error, while VC++ was left scratching its head.

Comment: The closing `>>` usually have space between them i.e. `> >`.

Comment: @Dilawar But if he has C++11 shouldn't this **not** be a problem?

Comment: @Dilawar Hm I was under the assumption that C++11 had fixed that issue. Regardless, the problem still occurs

Comment: @AK4749 I just read the documentation. It has been fixed. It should not be problem if compiler support it. I'll keep the comment there, it has some historical value now :p. Can you post a minimal code which reproduces the error? I am not on Windows right now, but someone must be kind enough to try it.

Comment: @0x499602D2 He is on VS2012. It's far from C++11-feature complete. That just wouldn't be MS style.

Comment: It hasn't been "fixed".  It's been changed.  Was not broken before.

Comment: @pmr While that is true - seeing as C++11 was delayed and did not fit MS's release cycle - the following link seems to indicate that it's been present since VS2010, years before C++11, correct? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh567368.aspx

Comment: Thank you all for your comments - I am still unable to solve the syntax issue and am working on an SSCE to reproduce it. On the other part, is this the best way for me to do what I am trying to accomplish? Thanks again

Comment: @AK4749 Yes, but I put little trust into VC and some of the odd bugs that show up in new features is further eroding it. My knee-jerk reaction is to blame VC as soon as the code looks OK, but is not accepted. They way you found the problem just proves my point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line from which you claim the error is occurring has little to do with the syntactic properties exclusive to C++11. Except for `std::function`, but if your compiler did not support that it wouldn't express its failure to compile with a syntax error.

Maybe the error is coming from the code below it. I don't think VS supports lambdas as of yet, this could probably be the source of the error. Note that your code compiles fine in [GCC](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=d876246f66bc8a9fa88cb29d04332843-8996fa4eaf2a653a1ca8b32f107442f6).

Comment: From the following link, I believe VS2010 supported most lambda functionality, while VS 2012 took care of the edge cases. I'll look into your "other line" suggestion though, and try to produce a SSCE. Thank you for your assistance! http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh567368.aspx

Comment: As an addendum, everything is wrapped in a namespace - I didn't think this would cause any issues, but could that be the case? EDIT: it doesn't change anything :/

Comment: exactly what you said - the error was coming from the code below it haha thanks!